# How to generate a rotated unitary matrix in excel

Tags: excel, matrix, transformation

Is possible in excel, with a cell formula, to generate a unitary matrix rotated 90 degrees?

For example, for size 3, to get this matrix:

```
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
```

I want to use it in array formulas, so I would prefer not to have the matrix written somewhere.

Note that the unitary matrix can ge generated with the formula =MUNIT(size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have MUNIT on my version of Excel but I can demonstrate the method like this

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,1,Size))=Size+1-ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,Size,1)),1,0)
```

i.e. set 1's in the matrix where the column = number of rows + 1 - row e.g. for row 1, set column 11-1 = 10 to a 1.

[image]

You can check that the matrix is correctly filled by entering the above as an array formula into (in this example) a 10 X 10 area of the sheet, or by using it in a function like SUM.

Comment: I still do not understand how the COLUMN function returns the ROW number, but it works. For example, if I MMULT your formula with a column, I get the column inverted. Have a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSnaUIeeF64

Comment: I've tried to clarify it a bit, because my text stated it the opposite way round to my formula. Meant to say also that if I could use MUNIT, it should lead to a simpler formula like =if(column(munit(size))=size+1-row(munit(size)),1,0) but I can't test this until I have access to Excel 365 which will be tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, I see A1:INDEX(1:1;1;Size) is a row

Comment: Yes in my case using a row of 10 cells with a column of 10 cells gives me a matrix of 100 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell along the first row, say **M1** and enter:

```
=IF(ROW()+COLUMN()=14,1,0)
```

*(Where the 14 corresponds to "M")*

copy this formula back towards **A1**.  Then copy row#1 downwards:

[image]

This is for a 13 **x** 13 matrix.

You can create any size matrix by picking the proper first row cell and choosing the associated value. *(This technique avoids the need for an array formula.)*

Comment: I do not need the matrix written in the worksheet. Otherwise I could simply write a large matrix, and select a piece of it. I actually want to use the matrix in array formulas.

Comment: @zexot I am sorry. I don't understand.

Comment: I need the matrix for intermediate calculations inside a single cell. I do not need to have the matrix shown in the worksheet.